# react native webview ios: should I intercept ajax request, and set headers of the request?

Tags: ajax, webview, header, react-native

I use react native's webview component, the situation is that I want to intercept ajax request, and set custom headers of the request, such as User-Agent, Referer, Cooike and so on, is there any solutions？

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem where I am wrapping an 3rd party web in React Native webview and in my case I needed to add `Authorization` header to every XHR (ajax) request.

One hack I came up with was to inject javascript into the webview that modifies prototype of `XMLHttpRequest.open` to intercept all requests from inside the web view.

We did not end up using this, but during testing it actually did work. I did not test this in Android but can't see why it should not work.

Here is a snippet from the POC that describes what I mean:

```
render() {
    const accessTokenInterceptor = this.buildAccessTokenInterceptorInjection(this.state.accessToken, "api.example.com");

    return (
        <WebView
            injectedJavaScript={accessTokenInterceptor}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            source={{
                uri: 'https://example.com'
            }}
        />
    );  
}

/**
 * This name might require an explanation :)
 *
 * AFAIK there is no simple way of intercepting XHR requests that are being made
 * from within the webview.
 *
 * A way to deal with this is to inject a script into the webview that modifies
 * XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open so that everytime it is invoked a headers is added.
 *
 * Yes, this is a hack - if you find any better solution, I'll buy you a beer!
 *
 */
buildAccessTokenInterceptorInjection(accessToken, whitelistedDomain) {
    return `
        (function() {
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

            var openWithAccessToken = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
                this.realOpen(method, url, async, user, password);

                if (url.indexOf('${whitelistedDomain}') > 0) {
                    this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ${accessToken}');
                }
            }

            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openWithAccessToken;
        })()
    `;
}
```